# How to configure vue project with custom configuration for prettier and eslint using vscode

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code, vuejs2, eslint, prettier

When I save the project into VSCode I'm getting wrong break like into html tags, how to solve it? The error is explaned into the code / images down.

[That is the non formated html.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E2IQT.png)

```
<div class="a" :class="3" :data-option="2" :id="1" :title="'a'">Abcatece</div>
```

[After run format getting that wrong formated Html Tags.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJfMq.png)

```
  <div class="a" :class="3" :data-option="2" :id="1" :title="'a'"
    >
    Abcatece
    </div
  >
```

[The formated html need to be in that way.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yo6H7.png)

```
 <div class="a" :class="3" :data-option="2" :id="1" :title="'a'">
   Some text here
 </div>
```

That is my configurations package.json and .prettierrc.js
Package.json

```
      "name": "project-name",
      "version": "0.1.0",
      "private": true,
      "scripts": {
        "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
        "build": "vue-cli-service build",
        "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
      },
      "dependencies": {
        "@coreui/coreui": "~3.0.0-beta.4",
        "@coreui/icons": "^1.0.1",
        "@coreui/icons-vue": "^1.3.1",
        "@coreui/utils": "^1.2.2",
        "@coreui/vue": "^3.0.0-beta.11",
        "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.13.0",
        "@joeattardi/emoji-button": "^2.12.1",
        "@microsoft/signalr": "3.1.3",
        "@toast-ui/editor": "^2.0.1",
        "axios": "^0.19.2",
        "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
        "bootstrap-vue": "^2.9.0",
        "highcharts": "^8.0.4",
        "highcharts-vue": "^1.3.5",
        "mic-recorder-to-mp3": "^2.2.1",
        "uuid": "^7.0.2",
        "vue": "^2.6.11",
        "vue-i18n": "8.16.0",
        "vue-notification": "1.3.20",
        "vue-router": "^3.1.6",
        "vue-select": "^3.9.5",
        "vuex": "^3.1.3"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^4.2.3",
        "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^4.2.3",
        "@vue/cli-service": "^4.2.3",
        "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
        "@vue/eslint-config-prettier": "^6.0.0",
        "babel-plugin-transform-remove-console": "^6.9.4",
        "core-js": "^3.6.4",
        "eslint": "^6.8.0",
        "prettier": "^2.0.2",
        "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.2",
        "eslint-plugin-vue": "^6.2.2",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11",
        "sass-loader": "^8.0.2",
        "node-sass": "^4.13.1"
      },
      "eslintConfig": {
        "root": true,
        "env": {
          "browser": true,
          "node": true,
          "es6": true
        },
        "extends": [
          "eslint:recommended",
          "@vue/prettier",
          "plugin:prettier/recommended",
          "plugin:vue/recommended"
        ],
        "rules": {
          "no-unused-vars": [
            "warn"
          ],
          "vue/component-tags-order": [
            "off",
            {
              "order": [
                "template",
                "script",
                "style"
              ]
            }
          ],
          "vue/singleline-html-element-content-newline": [
            "off",
            {
              "ignoreWhenNoAttributes": true,
              "ignoreWhenEmpty": true
            }
          ],
          "vue/html-indent": "off",
          "vue/html-self-closing": [
            "warn",
            {
              "html": {
                "normal": "any",
                "void": "any",
                "component": "any"
              }
            }
          ],
          "vue/attribute-hyphenation": [
            "off",
            {
              "ignore": []
            }
          ],
          "max-len": [
            "warn",
            {
              "code": 120,
              "ignoreComments": true
            }
          ],
          "vue/max-attributes-per-line": [
            "warn",
            {
              "singleline": 4,
              "multiline": {
                "max": 1,
                "allowFirstLine": true
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        "parserOptions": {
          "parser": "babel-eslint"
        }
      },
      "browserslist": [
        "> 1%",
        "last 2 versions"
      ]
    }
```

.prettierrc.js

```
module.exports = {
  tabWidth: 2,
  tabs: false,
  semi: true,
  singleQuote: false,
  quoteProps: "as-needed",
  trailingComma: "none",
  bracketSpacing: true,
  jsxBracketSameLine: true,
  arrowParens: "always",
  endOfLine: "lf",
  htmlWhitespaceSensitivity: "strict"
};
```

Comment: Can you reproduce this problem in [Prettier Playground](https://prettier.io/playground/)?

Comment: yes, thank you @GabrielWillemann , it's solved my problem. When  --html-whitespace-sensitivity is "strict" that happens on my code. But when I simple modified html-whitespace-sensitivity: 'css' or 'ignore' doens't happen anymore.